# Unable to login by using LinkidIn social login

Tags: django, linkedin-api

I am trying to login using social logins like google,github,facebook but when i am trying that in case of LinkedIn i am getting the following error

> HTTPError at /social/linkedin_login/
>
> HTTP Error 404: Not Found

I am user v2 for linkedin

views.py

```
required_info = "id,first-name,last-name,email-address,location,positions,educations,industry,summary,public-profile-url,picture-urls::(original)"
    rty = "https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me:(" + required_info + ")" + \
          "?format=json&oauth2_access_token="
    rty += accesstoken
    details = ur.urlopen(rty).read().decode('utf8')
```

I am getting error in details = ur.urlopen(rty).read().decode('utf8')

```
else:
    rty = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=" + \
        settings.LN_API_KEY
    rty += "&scope=r_liteprofile r_emailaddress w_member_social&state=8897239179ramya"
    rty += "&redirect_uri=" + request.scheme + '://' + \
        request.META['HTTP_HOST'] + reverse('social:linkedin_login')
    return HttpResponseRedirect(rty)
```

Can someone help me out of this error.

Comment: do you have any url `/social/linkedin_login/` in your urls.py?

Comment: No but i have linkedin_login in urls.py... `/social/linkedin_login/ `is for redirecting linkedin

Comment: are you using any library to integrate the linkedin login?

Comment: Yes i used oauth2client for every social logins...I wrote api for those...Everything is working except Linkedin

Answer (score 0):

The format you are using resembles LinkedIn's v1 API. You will need to update your request URL to be `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me`, with the OAuth 2.0 access token added to the `Authorization: Bearer` header.